# Is it necessary to use beta releases of Mac OS X as a development environment for beta releases of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Based on historical or current practice, is it necessary (or desired) to use beta versions of Mac OS X as a development environment for beta releases of iOS?

In the case of XCode, are the features/functionality that would be available only if the developer was using a pre-release version of Mac OS X? Are beta iOS SDKs always available to the current and supported Apple release of Mac OS X?

Comment: It seems odd that this question is being asked now and not during the iOS beta.

Comment: @rmaddy There's a beta Xcode out at the moment though.

Comment: @nevanking The Xcode 5.0.1 beta isn't associated with an iOS beta.

Answer (score 3):

No, as long as you can run the beta version of Xcode it's fine. The beta versions of Xcode that Apple distributes to run iOS betas with always work with the current (non-beta) version of OS X.

The beta versions of OS X are only needed to test applications that will run on those versions of OS X, they have nothing to do with iOS.